# selecting Business date taking into account for Holidays

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

trying to set two dates: End Date and Begin Date. Neither can be on weekend and neither can be on Holiday. End date has to be the most recent business date (t-1) and Begin Date has to be the  most recent business date before End date (t-2). The list of Holidays has to be maintained manually, seems all other resources available (Holiday library, workalendar library) aren't sufficient.

I tried and got stuck here:

```
import pandas as pd
import time
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta
import csv

enddate = datetime.today() - timedelta(days = 1)
if datetime.weekday(enddate) == 6:
    enddate = enddate - timedelta(days = 2)
elif datetime.weekday(enddate) == 5:
    enddate = enddate - timedelta(days = 1)

begdate = enddate - timedelta(days = 1)
if datetime.weekday(begdate) == 6:
    begdate = begdate - timedelta(days = 2)
elif datetime.weekday(begdate) == 5:
    begdate = begdate - timedelta(days = 1)
    
holidaylist = pd.read_csv('holiday.csv')
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Best regards,
Michael

Comment: Nvm, figured it out...

Comment: if you think your solution is helpful for others, you can answer your own question.

Comment: not sure if this is helpful as i'm still a dummy on python but i'll share what worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this work for me.
One downside is the list of Holidays have to be manually updated when required.

```
# Date Setup

holidaylist = pd.read_csv('holiday.csv')
holidaylist['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(holidaylist['Date'])

# enddate = date(2020, 12, 28)
enddate = datetime.today() - timedelta(days = 1)
while enddate in holidaylist.values or datetime.weekday(enddate) == 6 or datetime.weekday(enddate) == 5:
    enddate = enddate - timedelta(days = 1)

begdate = enddate - timedelta(days = 1)
while begdate in holidaylist.values or datetime.weekday(begdate) == 6 or datetime.weekday(begdate) == 5:
    begdate = begdate - timedelta(days = 1)

ed = enddate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
bd = begdate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                      
# print(ed,bd)
```